# Android: Activity not starting from a widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I am trying to launch an activity from a home screen widget. However, the activity is not starting when I click the widget. Below is my code.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingLayout = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingLayout);

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context,
            RecentTaskWidget.class.getName());

    mgr.updateAppWidget(comp, views);
}
```

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: Is MyActivity a Service? Then why it's called like that?

Comment: no... its another activity in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead of `PendingIntent.getService()`, probably this is why your code is not working. Hope this helps.

Comment: When is your onReceive() method getting called? As a matter of fact, usual place for binging Pending Intents to your AppWidget views is onUpdate() which is called right after the widget is created.

Comment: Finally found the problem. Instead of specifying view ID as an argument to setOnClickPendingIntent(), I was specifying the layout ID. Now its invoking the activity properly. Thx!